# Swipe usando a ferramenta Appium

Tags: android, mobile, testes

Estou aprendendo sobre uma nova ferramenta de testes automatizados mobile chamada Appium, e um dos testes que criei foi:

```
@Test
      public void Swipe () throws InterruptedException{
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        System.out.println("Vamos fazer swipe no tutorial");
        driver.swipe(75, 0, 500, 0, 10);
       }
```

ao executar o teste, ele passa. Porém, eu não consigo ver ele fazendo a função do swipe, não entendo como ele consegue passar. Porque será que ele passa?

O que eu queria obter com meu teste: fazer um swipe horizontal, da direita para a esquerda.

Answer (score 1):

Se você não inseriu nenhum assert no seu teste, e nenhuma linha de código disparou uma exceção, seu teste passará mesmo (porque não houve nenhum erro). 
Você deve conferir o estado do seu app após o executar o "swipe" usando algum Assert ou mesmo disparando uma exceção.

```
// assert com testng
Assert.assertEquals(<valor atual>, <valor esperado>);
// disparando exceção
throw new RuntimeException("Erro no app");
```

Veja um exemplo de como utilizar o método swipe (extraído de https://discuss.appium.io/t/screen-orientation-and-element-relative-swiping-tutorial/52)

```
public void swipeElementExample(WebElement el) {
  String orientation = driver.getOrientation().value();

  // pega a coordenada X do canto superior esquerdo do elemento, e adiciona a largura do elemento pra pegar o valor X da extrema direita do elemento
  int leftX = el.getLocation().getX();
  int rightX = leftX + el.getSize().getWidth();

  // pega a coordenada Y do canto superior esquedo do elemento e subtrai a altura pra pegar o menor valor Y do elemento
  int upperY = el.getLocation().getY();
  int lowerY = upperY - el.getSize().getHeight();
  int middleY = (upperY - lowerY) / 2;

  if (orientation.equals("portrait")) {
    // Swipe do centro-esquerdo para o centro-direito do elemento, em 500 ms
      driver.swipe(leftX + 5, middleY, rightX - 5, middleY, 500);
  }
  else if (orientation.equals("landscape")) {
    // Swipe do centro-direito para o centro-esquerdo do elemento, em 500ms
    driver.swipe(rightX - 5, middleY, leftX + 5, middleY, 500);
  }
}
```